# Transform this Javascript code to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I tried to transform the next piece of JS code into JQuery but It doesn't work. Could you help ?

```js
function initUpdateNavbarOnScroll() {
  var navbarc = document.querySelectorAll('#site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu>li>a');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= window.innerHeight) {
      navbarc.classList.add('darklinker');
    } else {
      navbarc.classList.remove('darklinker');
    }
  });
}

initUpdateNavbarOnScroll();
```

I've made different try if it helps but any of them works...

```js
// ​$( "#site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu>li>a" ).on( "scroll", function( event ) {
//     var navbarc = $( this );
//     if (window.scrollY >= window.innerHeight) {
//       navbarc.addClass('darklinker');
//     } else {
//       navbarc.removeClass('darklinker');
//     }
// });​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

// $( window ).scrollY(function() {
//   if ($( "site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu>li>a" )) {
//     navbarc.addClass('darklinker');
//   } else {
//     navbarc.removeClass('darklinker');
//   }
// });
```

Thx.

Comment: if the original works, why do you want to do this? That is so very odd!!

Comment: `if ($( "site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu>li>a" ))` this will always return true as `jQuery()` returns an object even if no elements are selected. Also there is no jQuery function named `scrollY()` unless you are using some plugin library.

Comment: @RandyCasburn [needs more jquery](http://needsmorejquery.com/)

Comment: @ASDFGerte - Ah! I see bwahaha Thanks for that

Comment: Well, the problem is that the `querySelectorAll` doesn't work but the `querySelector`do his job. But I want to select them all...

I asked to the theme owner and he told me to write it in JQuery because it's load in the theme.  

They should have a conflict somewhere, i think but don't know where exactly...

Answer (score 1):

```
function initUpdateNavbarOnScroll() {
    var navbarc = $("#site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu>li>a");

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      if (window.scrollY >= window.innerHeight) {
        navbarc.addClass('darklinker');
      } else {
        navbarc.removeClass('darklinker');
      }
    });
}

initUpdateNavbarOnScroll();
```

Answer (score 0):

But why mannnn???????

```
function initUpdateNavbarOnScroll() {
    var navbarc = $('#site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu>li>a');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(window).innerHeight() ) {
            navbarc.addClass('darklinker);
        } else {
            navbarc.removeClass('darklinker);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I loaded the code with the missing ' ' ->
` 
function initUpdateNavbarOnScroll() {
    var navbarc = $('#site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu>li>a');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if( $(window).scrollTop() >= $(window).innerHeight() ) {
            navbarc.addClass('darklinker');
        } else {
            navbarc.removeClass('darklinker');
        }
    });
}

initUpdateNavbarOnScroll();
`
But it doesn't work. Basicly I asked for JQuery because the `querySelectorAll`didn't work (versus the `querySelector`who's working)
But I want to select them all